# array_combine and create new array in this array with array_combine

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is what i have now.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1
        [y] => 1418
        [z] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [x] => 2
        [y] => 567
        [z] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [x] => 3
        [y] => 2345
        [z] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [x] => 4
        [y] => 567
        [z] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1
        [y] => 2134
        [z] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [x] => 2
        [y] => 456
        [z] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [x] => 3
        [y] => 1418
        [z] => 2
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [x] => 4
        [y] => 676
        [z] => 2
    )
)
```

And I want have:

```
Array(
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
             (
                [y] => 1418
             )
        [2] => Array
             (
                [y] => 567
             )
        [3] => Array
             (
                [y] => 2345
             )
        [4] => Array
             (
                [y] => 567
             )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
             (
                [y] => 2134
             )
        [2] => Array
             (
                [y] => 456
             )
        [3] => Array
             (
                [y] => 1418
             )
        [4] => Array
             (
                [y] => 676
             )
    )
)
```

Now, a little explanation. I want from this array, I created a new array where: 
[z] = was a key on first array
[x] = was a key on second array.

[z] and [x] does not have to be removed from the array.

Could someone help me how to do it? Because scheming and does not go to me. In particular, I have a problem with the creation of a new array inside this.

var_export:

```
array (
   0 => 
   array (
       'x' => '1',
       'y' => '1418',
       'z' => '1',
   ),
   1 => 
   array (
       'x' => '2',
       'y' => '567',
       'z' => '1',
   ),
   2 => 
   array (
       'x' => '3',
       'y' => '2345',
       'z' => '1',
   ),
   3 => 
   array (
       'x' => '4',
       'y' => '567',
       'z' => '1',
   ),
   4 => 
   array (
       'x' => '1',
       'y' => '2134',
       'z' => '2',
   ),
   5 => 
   array (
       'x' => '2',
       'y' => '456',
       'z' => '2',
   ),
   6 => 
   array (
       'x' => '3',
       'y' => '1418',
       'z' => '2',
   ),
   7 => 
   array (
       'x' => '4',
       'y' => '676',
       'z' => '2',
   ),
)
```

Comment: use var_export() to help others help you by providing a sample array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is what you are looking for.

Is your case you want: `array_chunk($array, 4)`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that they are always in the same order, but just see if if they were in the same order, whether it is a good way out. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Looks good, works like I want, thanks and sorry for the simple questions.